# Maintain State of Previous Page After Clicking LinkButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

in linkbtn

```
protected void lnkBtnSun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["employeeName"] = txt_EmpName.Text;
        Session["Projectstaus"] = ddownList.SelectedValue;
        Session["Startdate"] = txt_StartDate.Text;
        Session["EndDate"] = txt_EndDate.Text;
        Session["lblsun"] = lbl_sun.Text;
        Session["lblmon"] = lbl_Mon.Text;
    }
```

in timesheet.aspx

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    string employeeName = (Session["employeeName"] != null) ? Session["employeeName"] : "";//cursor moves from textbox dropdown data is  disappering
    string projectStatus = (Session["Projextstaus"] != null) ? Session["Projextstaus"] : "";//maintains value when retun back from another webform
    string startDate = (Session["Startdate"] != null) ? Session["Startdate"] : "";
    string endDate = (Session["EndDate"] != null) ? Session["EndDate"] : "";//String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
    string lblsun = (Session["lblsun"] != null) ? Session["lblsun"] : "";
    string lblmon = (Session["lblmon"] != null) ? Session["lblmon"] : "";
   }
```

maintain state of previous page  when I click on linkbutton 
I have two webforms in on webform I contross when i click on linkbutton it goes to  nextpage ther if im done while retunrsn to main page im loosing data in mainpage ,I tried session but not worked.

```
txt_EmpName.Text = (Session["employeeName"] != null) ? Session["employeeName"].ToString() : "";

ddownList.SelectedValue = (Session["Projectstaus"] != null) ? Session["Projectstaus"].ToString() : "";
```

Comment: Do you mean viewstate or session? Your code samples use Session, but your description talks about view state.

Comment: I'm afraid your description of the problem is unclear - "contross", "if im done while retunrsn to main page" etc. I realise that English may not be your first language, but would it be possible to edit your answer and clarify exactly what your issue is?

Answer (score 0):

Session is the typical solution in these scenarios. Are you writing those properties to the Session object? Otherwise, they will always be `null` and you'll see the behavior you're describing.